# Debugging xmodmap

Tags: linux, x-windows, xmodmap

I did something stupid. I was screwing around with xmodmap a few weeks back, and gave up what I was trying to do. I find out later that Shift-J no longer does anything (I can't type capital "J").

`xmodmap -pke` shows the following for what appears to be the "J" key:

```
keycode  44 = j J j J
```

I want to restore normal behavior for Shift-J. Where do I start?

Comment: I laughed out loud at this. But seriously, this setting is in a file somewhere. Did you save this in a startup file of some sort, or did `xmodmap` create the file automatically?

Comment: Damned if I know. I probably just need to find that file. Two of my clients' names start with "J" and it's starting to get annoying.